# Image downloaded but can't open show the format is unsupported or corrupted

Tags: javascript, url, fetch-api, imagedownload

This is my code:

```
function downloadImage(url) {
      fetch(url, {
     mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    .then(response => response.blob())
     .then(blob => {
        let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        a.href = blobUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
        })
 }

 var url = 'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital- 
 windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg';

 downloadImage(url)
```

When I run this code it's download the image successfully but when I open the image it's shows **Sorry, Photos can't open this file because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted** Can anyone tell me please why it's happening and how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Is this **exactly** the code you are using? If so, you could try to remove the break in the link string and see if it works

Comment: Remove the spaces in `digital-  windows-11`

Comment: @Apollo79 can you give me a hint how can I do that...

Comment: use ['https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital-windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg'](https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital-windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg) instead of ['https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital- 
 windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg'](https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital- 
 windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg).

Comment: I know, it looks almost similar, but the break inside the string is whitespace (and there are spaces, too), so the URL is not the same.

Comment: I have same issue! Any solution yet? Code works fine with .pdf files but not .jpg and .png

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same problem with .jpg/.png ... pdf works

Answer (score 0):

The image url you are using is blocking your request hence you are getting empty blob.

I have tried your code with unsplash image it is working.

```
   async function downloadImage(url) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const blob = await res.blob();
        const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, "");
        a.href = blobUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    const url =
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644982647844-5ee1bdc5b114?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60";

    downloadImage(url);
```